# alternative of grep in python running on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, grep

I'm extracting the first line that starts with 'abc' in a file

```
grep -w 'abc' --max-count=1 file.tsv
```

I wanna use it in a python program

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("grep -w 'abc' --max-count=1 file.tsv",
                             shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           )
stdout = process.communicate()[0].split('\n')
```

My python is running on `Windows` and `grep` won't work. Is there an alternative that I can use in my python program.

Comment: The alleged duplicate points to Unix, this is a `Windows` issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into re: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Open the file and search the lines using re; this would eliminate the need to call a sub-process.

Answer (score 1):

in Windows try this:

```
grep -w "abc" --max-count=1 file.tsv
```

[grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) needs `"`double quotes`"`.